# structure of a php file from a facebook button redirect

Tags: php, html, facebook-graph-api

I am running a php page which i get to via a redirect from facebook api button:

```
<fb:login-button    class="fb-login-button" scope="user_birthday,offline_access,publish_stream'" 
                        onlogin="window.location='xxxxx.php';">Connect with Facebook</fb:login-button>
```

I my target page I don't have any html, I just have

```
<?php
code.....
echo '';

if (xxx)
header("Location: http://xxxx.com/xxx.php"); 

?>
```

my question is, is this correct?
Where would the echo data output go to if I don't have any html tags?

Should I add html,head,body tags to this page?

My page is not running correct, that is way I am asking.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on what you want to echo. it doesn't have to be html, it can also be plain text.

What you definitely can't do is echo before sending headers: ([php header](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.header.php))

> Remember that header() must be called before any actual output is
> sent, either by normal HTML tags, blank lines in a file, or from PHP.
>
> It is a very common error to read code with include(), or require(),
> functions, or another file access function, and have spaces or empty
> lines that are output before header() is called. The same problem
> exists when using a single PHP/HTML file.